# Can't connect database container with server container using a single pod

Tags: kubernetes, podman

I am creating a POD file with multiple containers. One is a webserver container and another is my PostgreSQL container. Here is my pod file named `simple.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-01T16:28:15Z"
  labels:
    app: eltask
  name: eltask
spec:
  containers:
  - name: el_web
    command:
      - ./entrypoints/entrypoint.sh
    env:
    - name: PATH
      value: /usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    - name: TERM
      value: xterm
    - name: container
      value: podman
    - name: RUBY_MAJOR
      value: "2.7"
    - name: BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING
      value: "1"
    - name: BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG
      value: /usr/local/bundle
    - name: LANG
      value: C.UTF-8
    - name: RUBY_VERSION
      value: 2.7.2
    - name: RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256
      value: 1b95ab193cc8f5b5e59d2686cb3d5dcf1ddf2a86cb6950e0b4bdaae5040ec0d6
    - name: GEM_HOME
      value: /usr/local/bundle
    image: docker.io/hmtanbir/elearniotask
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
      hostPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      capabilities:
        drop:
        - CAP_MKNOD
        - CAP_NET_RAW
        - CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
      privileged: false
      readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      seLinuxOptions: {}
    tty: true
    workingDir: /app
  - name: el_db
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:10-alpine3.13
    env:
      - name: PATH
        value: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
      - name: TERM
        value: xterm
      - name: container
        value: podman
      - name: PG_MAJOR
        value: "10"
      - name: PG_VERSION
        value: "10.17"
      - name: PGDATA
        value: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      - name: LANG
        value: en_US.utf8
      - name: PG_SHA256
        value: 5af28071606c9cd82212c19ba584657a9d240e1c4c2da28fc1f3998a2754b26c
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        value: password
    args:
      - postgres
    command:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - containerPort: 5432
        hostPort: 9876
        protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
      capabilities:
        drop:
          - CAP_MKNOD
          - CAP_NET_RAW
          - CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
        privileged: false
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
        seLinuxOptions: {}
    tty: true
    workingDir: /
  dnsConfig: {}
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

I am running a webserver container in `3000:3000` port and the DB container port is `9876:5432`.
But when I run cmd using PODMAN `podman play kube simple.yaml`, DB container is running `127.0.0.0:9876` but webserver can't connect with the DB server.

[image]

My webserver DB config:

```
ELTASK_DATABASE_HOST=localhost
ELTASK_DATABASE_PORT=9876
ELTASK_DATABASE_USERNAME=postgres
ELTASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
```

If I run the webserver without Podman, the server can connect with the DB using `9876` port.

So, Why the webserver can't connect with the database container while it is running through Podman?

Comment: If postgres only needs to be accessed from the _el_web_ container, I think you can remove _- containerPort: 5432 
 hostPort: 9876      protocol: TCP_  . See for instance the section _The Pod Spec_ in this [example](https://handsonscale.com/index.php/2020/03/30/kubernetes-101-part-12-multi-container-pods/)

Comment: Neither creating a bare Pod nor putting multiple containers in a Pod are typically considered best practices.  Can you run a Deployment for your application, and a separate StatefulSet for the database, plus a matching Service for each?

Comment: @ErikSjölund thanks, now my pod is working.

Answer (score 1):

For your web container to connect to the postgresql container within the pod, use `ELTASK_DATABASE_PORT=5432` instead of ELTASK_DATABASE_PORT=9876.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

There are two parts of the answer:

1. **Which port to use and why**

For `postgresql` as a backend service, you can omit the `hostPort` since `podman` as a frontend service will access `postresql` using `Cluster-IP` and therefore it will be available on port `5432`. Completely deleting this part is not recommended approach, when you have a lot of pods with containers inside, it's much better to be able to quickly see which container is exposed on which port.

Also in general `hostPort` shouldn't be used unless it's the only way, consider using `NodePort`:

> Don't specify a hostPort for a Pod unless it is absolutely necessary.
> When you bind a Pod to a hostPort, it limits the number of places the
> Pod can be scheduled, because each <hostIP, hostPort, protocol>
> combination must be unique.

See [best practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#services).

2. **Frontend and backend deployment**

It's always advisable and a best practice to separate backend and frontend into different `deployments`, so they can be managed fully separately like upgrades, replicas and etc. As well as `services` - you don't need to expose backend service outside the cluster.

See [an frontend and backend example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/).

Also @David Maze correctly said that database should use a `statefulSet` - see [more details about Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).